# Multiply each element of 2 numpy arrays and then sum up

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Basically I have two 1d numpy arrays, let's call them x and y, both of the same length. I want to essentially get the result x1*y1 + x2*y2 + ... + xn*yn. Obviously I could do this with a for loop but is there a built-in method or something where I can do this in one line?

Comment: What code have you tried, possibly including any code that may have `for` loops?

Comment: I'm specifically trying to do it in one line

Comment: `(x * y).sum()`?

Comment: @user3483203 That works!! If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to compute is known as an 'inner product' and, in the case of two vectors, is called a 'dot product'.  Numpy has built-in functions for computing both which are optimized for speed over the simple `(x*y).sum()` solution.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([3, 2, 1])

print(np.inner(a, b))
# 10

print(np.dot(a, b))
# 10
```

Some timing results in the table below with vectors `a` and `b` being 1000 randomly selected elements using `np.random.randn`:

```
np.dot(a, b)   # 920 ns ±  9.9 ns
np.inner(a, b) # 1.1 µs ± 83.5 ns
(a*b).sum()    # 4.2 µs ± 62.9 ns
np.sum(a*b)    # 5.7 µs ± 170  ns
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum(x*y)` or `(x*y).sum()`, they're equivalent.